# Displaying datatable pagination based on an API pagination object

Tags: javascript, datatables

I want to use JQuery datatable to display data on an HTML table but the data is coming from an API endpoint that uses pagination. The pagination object contains a detailed description of the pages - next page, number of pages, etc. How do I use this information to alter datatable's default pagination schema? I want the table to show either next or previous depending on information from the pagination object.

Here is the sample pagination object

```
"page_details": {
  "has_next_page": true,
  "has_previous_page": false,
  "next_page": 2,
  "previous_oage": 0,
  "total": 24
}
```

Here is my datatable:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('#myTable').DataTable();
});
```

Comment: You need server side processing to true. Here is the answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924546/server-side-pagination-using-datatables

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Server side pagination using datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924546/server-side-pagination-using-datatables)

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution ? I'm almost done but not able to link the next and previous page to my links inside my API. Thank !